# Can't add any API/WSDLs

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to run through the Quick Start Guide in the API Manager documentation and can't seem to add any WSDL/ASMX endpoints.  They open fine in the browser but fail when adding through the API Pulisher tool.

When enter in http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx for the endpoint and click the Test button, all I get is "Invalid".  Same thing for entering the WSDL: http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl.

I hope there is a way to get error details because "Invalid" isn't all that helpful.

I am behind a company proxy but my Internet Options (Windows 8.1) is properly setup and both of those Urls work properly in IE and Chome.

Comment: Which version of API Manager version you are using?

Comment: The latest 4.6.0.  I have the Governance Registry and the API Manager installed and running.

Comment: Not 4.6.0, it should be 1.6.0. But the latest one is 1.7.0, and this bug is fixed in API Manager 1.8.0 which will be released in another two weeks!

Comment: You are probably referring to the API creator\publisher portal.  I am in something that shows API Manager in the upper left and Management Console in upper right. When I click About it shows 4.6.0 and says WSO2 Governance Registry.  I have tried to add a WSDL and normally it shows "There are no WSDLs added".  For a short period of time it actually showed the various attempts I made and looked like it was working properly.  Now it is back to displaying "There are no WSDLs added".  Thanks for the responses BTW!

Comment: So figured out why the API Manager console would work sometimes - WSO2 Governance Manager was trying to use the same port as the API Manager so I changed the offset in the config to 1. Still getting the "Invalid" error when adding an API. The logs show "Failed to reset the WSDL" "connection refused".  I added some proxy info since we are behind a company proxy but that didn't work. Still plodding along :-)